# .click js is fired twice, if another js is present

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following html

```
<div id="personalText" >
    <div class="display">
        <a href="#" id="editButton"> edit </a>
        <p id="descText">{{profile.desc}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="edit" style="display:none;">
        <textarea cols='40' rows='9' id="desc_text" style="border:none; display:block;">{{profile.desc}}</textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Update"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is piece of `js` I have

```
$("#editButton").click(function() {
    $(".display, .edit").toggle();
    var desc_text = $("#desc_text").text();
    return false;
});

$("input[type='submit']").on("click", function() {
    var dec_text = $('#desc_text').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:"/users/update_desc/",
        data: {
        'val': dec_text,
        },
    }).success(function(){
        $(".display, .edit").toggle();
        $("#descText").html(dec_text);
    });
    return false;
});
```

The problem is that the `$("#editButton").click(function()` is fired twice if the js snippet below it is present, however if I comment out the `$("input[type='submit']").on("click", function()` then it is working fine.

Also the `textarea` should show the text inside it, but it is does not display anything. Although the `text` is present there but it does not show it.

Comment: I could not reproduce both the issues. Here is the JSFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/B8qW7/     Can you try to reproduce your issues in this jsfiddle?

Comment: How do you determine that `#editButton` click handler is fired twice?

Comment: @liho1eye: I added an alert call withing the click handler and it came up twice when I had clicked only once.

Comment: have you tried to validate your code? Could be depending by a malformed markup?

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan Strangely when I replaced the submit button by a link and then used the same code replacing button with a link, everything seems to be working fine. This problem might be because of some other thing that is there in the code